# Update error (stretch)

Tags: raspbian-stretch, update

Hello, I'm Jinny Park.
I bought the raspberry pi 3 b+ version, but it didn't work anything.
It didn't upgraded.

- Linux
- SAMSUNG 32 GB SD CARD.

root@nsdkr11:/m apt-get update
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'

[image]

Comment: Did you post this via one of those mail robots for people who refuse to have a web browser? Anyway, looks like you have a network problem. Try again, and find out your network configuration if trying again didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Your Raspberry Pi cannot resolve the URLs (e.g. `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian`) to retrieve the files it needs to perform the upgrade you've asked it to perform. This means you have not set up your network properly. This could be the result of any number of things, but try this first:

Start raspi-config (`sudo raspi-config`) from the command line, then go into item 2, and configure your WiFi credentials.

If that doesn't resolve things and allow the upgrade, post the details here, and we'll try to help you resolve that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error right now, and others using PlusNet have [reported similarly](https://community.plus.net/t5/Broadband/raspberrypi-org-not-accessible-on-PlusNet/m-p/1548572).

I could solve this problem by switching my DNS server to Google DNS, as explained on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/617796/how-do-i-set-dns-servers-on-raspberry-pi), by adding a line to `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: How did you determine the OP was using PlusNet?

Comment: I'm not using PlusNet, yet the domain is completely down for me, I can't pull any packages. As far as I can tell, multiple providers are affected and the fault probably lies with raspberrypi.org itself.

Comment: You said, "... others using PlusNet have reported similarly." That woould imply that you've somehow connected PlusNet to the issue. Not trying to be picky, I'm only trying to follow your logic. Also, [raspberrypi.org has reported making some DNS changes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=216809) that *may* have caused the issue, but if that's the case, using Google's DNS wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Your quote is from Aurora0001 who rewrote my answer, I simply wrote that others have these problems too, me included. I still can't resolve raspberrypi.org through my providers DNS, but it works perfectly with Google DNS.

Comment: Ha ha - ok, sorry... you can't defend what you didn't write. Odd issue though; hope you get it sorted soon enough. DNS changes do take days sometimes to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My /etc/resolv.conf file only had 127.0.0.1 as the dns, after adding 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 I was able to upgrade.

If you are using dhcp then in order to update the file you need to change the dhcpd file:

`sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

add this to the bottom of the file to add the cloudflare dns servers:

`static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1`

or alternatively the google domain servers

`static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8`

then just restart the dhcp service and you should be good to proceed with your upgrades:

`sudo service dhcpcd restart`